# How to bypass the time interval defined in server for each request with Jmeter

Tags: php, security, jmeter, penetration-testing

My website has been hacked with sending two concurrent request by an attacker.
Two same post request has been received in server which is as follows:

[image: jmeter request I created]

[image]

The attacker made two concurrent request to the server and bought  2 items of the same price with having only price of one in his wallet of my website.

so I simulated the same request in jmeter to send 2 or more request to the server at same time with sync timer.But Since I have implemented a function in such a way that if one transaction is done, it should not process the second post request of transaction from the same uid and  denomi(you can find these two in the parameter field of this request in the above image.).

Here is my code

[image: php code for not processing request for another 20 seconds]

So when I did this with jmeter with two concurrent request:
one of them succeeded and the second one got the message "You did a similar order less than 20 seconds ago."

Is there a way somehow to replicate what the attacker did to bypass this? or is there a way to do concurrent request to a server where these kind of delay is implemented?

I need to send concurrent request in such a way that it will not go to the if condition or it should not create a flag in database setting that transaction is already done. By manipulation the server time? Or am I going completely wrong here with sending concurrent request? would there be any other backdoor to this? Any one have idea?

What I tried:
concurrent request with sync timer and ramp up 0
utf 8 encoding and decoding of amount and denomi in request parameter field
intercept the request with burpsuite for possible manipulation. 
Nothing worked out

Comment: Your server wasn't hacked. You screwed up. You need to be using database transactions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz, Implementing the Database Transaction methods  is also one of the thing that I started implementing for further security.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the issue. It was not only about concurrent request rather it was also about the request header data.  And it also doesnt depend upon the 20 second delay between the transaction.

How I reproduced the issue:
1. Created 2 identical request to do the payment with wallet in jmeter under 2 thread groups in such a way that these request will be sent at the same time.
2. But changed the referrer URL of one to request another url where some other item is purchased.
3.And hence the active item is being sold two times with price of only one. The system actually deduct the money in the wallet but if the user has only price to buy one item. its simply buys two items and send it to the user with deducting only once.

Its a loophole in the dev code.

Fixed by :

1. Transaction lock in database
2. Removing creation of session in particular pageload
3. Creating the request post variables in the requests being sent
4. And finally for additional security- Implemented CORS